How to convert .wav file to a numpy array and then back to a .wav file format without losing quality/having the same audio without any noise?
I seem to be unable to convert a .wav file to a numpy array , and then back to .wav. The audio gets too noisy.
I tried using scipy.io.wavfile.read() ,and librosa.
The whole reason I am trying to do that is because transcribe() function from openai-whisper accepts only file path or a numpy array ( as far as I know). As I would like my code to run on a  google cloud, specifying a file path is not possible. My attempts to use BytesIO() are for naught.
Just in case, I am a novice in the field of programming. Any help would be appreciated.
example code:
speaking_model = whisper.load_model("base")

path=r'...\..wav'
output_path = r'\...\.wav'
original_sample_rate, numpy = wavfile.read(path)
numpy=numpy.astype(np.float32)
print(numpy,'datratatatta', numpy.dtype)
# Create an AudioSegment from the numpy array

audio_segment = AudioSegment(
    numpy.tobytes(), 
    frame_rate=original_sample_rate,
    sample_width=numpy.dtype.itemsize,
    channels=1
)

# Export the audio segment to a file
audio_segment.export(output_path, format='wav')

# Optional: You can still export to BytesIO if needed
audio_data = io.BytesIO()
audio_segment.export(audio_data, format='wav')
audio_data.seek(0)  # Seek to the start of the BytesIO object


result=speaking_model.transcribe(numpy)
print(result["text"])

Guys, I have found a solution , well it does not read a numpy array (could not do that), but .transcribe() now reads bytes . There is a pull request in github : https://github.com/openai/whisper/pull/1980/commits/e000892e137fb17d4ab43046c77853274eaf9ed2 ,  take it, modify the files and .transcribe() will accept bytes
for example:
 original_sample_rate, numpy = wavfile.read(path)
    
    print('ORIGINAL SAMPLE RATE:', original_sample_rate)
    
    new_sample_rate = 16000
    
    number_of_samples = round(len(numpy) * float(new_sample_rate) / original_sample_rate)
    
    resampled_data = resample(numpy, number_of_samples)
    
    if numpy.dtype == np.int16:
        new_bit_depth_data = resampled_data.astype(np.int16)
    else:
        # Scale and convert to 16-bit
        new_bit_depth_data = (resampled_data / np.max(np.abs(resampled_data)) * 32767).astype(np.int16)
    buferus=io.BytesIO()
    wavfile.write(buferus, new_sample_rate, new_bit_depth_data)
    buferus=buferus.getbuffer()
    buferus=buferus.tobytes()
    result = speaking_model.transcribe(buferus)
    message=result["text"]
    print('MESSAGE:', message) 


Now I don't have to create a local file !
If anyone finds a way to pass a numpy array, I would be greatful, for now I will use a modified library


"As I would like my code to run on a google cloud, specifying a file path is not possible." Pretty much all google cloud products that let you run custom Python code will let you write to a temporary file and then read it back. Are you sure that using a file is not possible? Can you provide more details about the cloud environment where this is running?

"I tried using scipy.io.wavfile.read() ,and librosa." This will likely not work. Whisper is expecting 16 kHz sample rate audio. If you read a wav file with a 44 kHz sample rate, without downsampling, then every sound in the file will sound 3x deeper and 3x slower to Whisper. Similarly, librosa resamples to 22 kHz sample rate, which is also not the sample rate that Whisper is expecting.

I have actually tried resampling to 16kHZ, maybe I was doing something wrong. I have also tried to use google cloud storage , transcribe() requires the file path or numpy array, so it did not work
